# how to set approval of admin for wordpress posts submitted by the user?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, buddypress

i'm using [BuddyPress bp-simple-front-end-post(addon)](https://buddydev.com/plugins/bp-simple-front-end-post/) in my wordpress for users to post on my site from front-end.

is it possible for the posts submitted by user will need admin approval. ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [BuddyPress Moderation Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpressmoderation/) which does this. As of time of writing this plugin is old and looking unmaintained, however I think it's active on a site I'm admin and will work for what you need.